# Sending notification in android

Tags: java, android

I want to send a notification through my app to a phone that runs Android 8 or newer (26+ API Level) but nothing seems to work even the way the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)
shows. Can someone help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "myChannel";
    int id = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "myName", importance);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    public void onBtnClick(View view){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Text")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
        id++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: Try [another guide](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int notificationId  = new Random().nextInt();
    String channelId  = "Messages";
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this,channelId );
    builder.setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher );
    builder.setContentTitle( "Title" );
    builder.setContentText( "Subtitle" );
    builder.setStyle( new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(
            "Subtitle"
    ) );
    builder.setPriority( NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT );
    builder.setContentIntent( null );
    builder.setAutoCancel( true );

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        CharSequence channelName = "Channel name";
        String channelDescription = "Channel Description";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel( channelId,channelName,importance );
        channel.setDescription( channelDescription );
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService( NotificationManager.class );
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( channel );
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from( this );
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(notificationId,builder.build());
```